# How can I format a floating point number in Scala inside a StringBuilder?

Tags: scala

Good evening SO,

I want to format a floating point number in Scala within my StringBuilder. The code below works but is verbose. Surely there's a more concise way to do the same thing.

Thank you.

```
var myDouble: Double = 1.23456789
val stringBuilder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
stringBuilder.append(s"My double: ${BigDecimal(myDouble).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)}")
println(stringBuilder.toString())
```

Comment: codereview should be the better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
new StringBuilder(f"$myDouble%.5f")
res0: StringBuilder = 1.23457
```